# Dividing a binary square matrix into smaller matrices

Tags: matlab

I have a binary matrix of size 200x200:

```
matrix=double(rand(200,200)>0.5));
```

I want to divide this matrix into smaller pieces, e.g. 4 squares of 100x100, 16 squares of 50x50, 64 squares of 25x25 and after that into 64 squares 5x5x5x5 pieces since 25 is an odd number. Then I want to count the ones in the resulting matrices.

I'm looking for an elegant solution without using many loops and looking for some inspirations or helpful matlab functions :).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is precisely what [`mat2cell`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mat2cell.html) is meant to do. This will work for non-square images as well

```
dims = floor(size(img) / n);
output = mat2cell(img(1:dims(1)*n, 1:dims(2)*n), ...
                  ones(1, dims(1)) * n, ones(1, dims(2)) * n);
```

This passes a subset of `img` to `mat2cell` to account for cases when `img` is not a whole-number multiple of `n`.

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Learning a lot through that example. Thank you the second time for today :).

Comment: @holistic Updated my answer with the more sane solution.

Comment: I see! Great solution as well..either way, can learn a lot from both solution :)

Comment: @holistic updated to deal with matrices that aren't a whole number multiple of `n`.

Comment: Ah yes, I got this error message..works like a charm now. Thanks again!!